# Submitting third version of an iOS app via iTunesConnect before app goes live

Tags: ios, ipad, release, app-store-connect

We have an iOS app which has been approved for release with its version 1.0 **and** we submitted a minor update, version 1.1 that was also approved, and is "Pending Developer Release". The date set for first availability in "Rights and Pricing" is a month from now.

The question is the following - is it possible to submit another update (lets say version 1.2) without forcing the app to go live early? That is, if we click "Release this Version" on the app version 1.1 page, will it actually make the app go live in the app store immediately? Or will iTunes honor the date in "Rights and Pricing" and the app will remain unreleased, and we would be able to submit another update in the now-open version slot?

The copy in the Apple Developer Support manual seems to indicate that the app **will** go live when pushing Release This Version, but it is not clear:

p. 72:

> Availability Date
>
> The date when your app will be available for purchase on the App
>   Store. If your application has not been approved by Apple prior to
>   this date, your app will go live as soon as it has been approved.
>
> This is a global date, and applies to all territories selected. If you
>   change this date, it will apply to all versions of your application.
>   If you create a new version of your app, you may use the Version
>   Release Control feature in order to control the date your new version
>   is released to the App Store.

p.73:

> NOTE: You can only use the Version Release Control on app updates. It
>   is not available for the first version of your app since you already
>   have the ability to control when your first version goes live, using
>   the Availability Date setting within Rights and Pricing. If you decide
>   that you do not want to ever release a Pending Developer Release
>   version, you can reject your binary to submit a new one. You are not
>   permitted to skip over an entire version.

Comment: How did you get 1.1 submitted without releasing 1.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We just tested this and it appears that after you press "RELEASE THIS VERSION" on the 1.1 version, the app is actually still held back until you set the release date in the "Rights and Pricing" section (as long as you haven't yet released the app). So it is possible to continue submitting further updates to an app before releasing it to the public.

Comment: Found to still be the case by us on 7/25/12

Comment: Still the case when we did this 7/17/14

Answer (score 1):

This answer from iTunes Connect  I got on 12th March 2014, with availability date in "Rights and Pricing" section set to 4/1/14 (1st April 2014):

> I understand that you have set the available date of version 1.0.1 of
>   your app to 4/1/14. If you click the 'Release This Version' button
>   prior to 4/1/14 this will override the available date and the app will
>   go live within 24 hours of the date that you clicked 'Release This
>   Version.'
>
> Version 1.0.1 will be displayed as an update to your app. For more
>   tips and information on gaining visibility for your app, please refer
>   to the App Store Resource Center - Marketing Resources:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/marketing/index.html

So it states the opposite of what MobileVet experienced around 7/25/12, as their app was held back until the release date (availability date ?) set in "Rights and Pricing" section.

From App Store Marketing I received such a answer when I asked if updating the app before the release would influence initial exposure:

> This will not affect your potential feature placement.  I'd suggest you update so your app is a best as possible on release.

Comment: I've also seen this happen. I hit the "Release This Version" button - then immediately went to amend the release date (which was still set in the far-future) in "Rights and Pricing" to be "tomorrow". But... I later saw several downloads on the day I hit the "Release This Version" button. Implying it was available for a short time before my subsequent edit to the release date.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a new version you are usually asked if you want to release it immediately or wait for manual release, usually just before uploading. I think this is what you want to do.