# iOS - Test app store binary before release?

Tags: ios, testing, release, app-store-connect

I had read once that if in iTunes Connect you marked a binary as "hold for developer release", there was a way to install that version from the app store instead of the current version in the store - thus allowing for one final check that the binary was good before release, and to ensure which binary was actually submitted.

I was unable to find a way to link to the approved binary though in a recent submission.  Does anyone know how you can install an app store binary that has been approved before you release it?

Answer (score 4):

What I do is an archive build (a release build). Then in the Organizer I choose the archive and then distribute it as an ad-hoc build. The resulting ipa file gets installed into iTunes then that version gets synced to an iOS device for testing. If it all looks good I then go back to the Organizer and choose the same archive. This time I choose to do an App Store distribution and submit the app to Apple for review.

The only difference between what you end up testing and what ends up in the App Store is how the app is signed. It's the same binary otherwise.

Comment: Not exactly true, provisioning profiles for example are embedded in an ad-hoc build, they do not exist in an app store release.  I do also test ad-hoc builds frequently but there have been past instances where the app store binary had some quirk not caught in ad-hoc testing.

Comment: The app binary is exactly the same as well as all of the app resources. The `embedded.mobileprovision` file is the only thing that would be different.

Comment: That's what you'd think but past experience begs to differ.  I have absolutely seen an app store binary that crashed on launch in a way no ad-hoc build ever did - on the same device...

Comment: Testing release builds is a must do practice. Learned that the hard way today. Thanx for the post.

Comment: I was going to add that rather than using iTunes to install grab iFunBox (free) which has an ipa installer. Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the answer in the response to this question:

[Submitting third version of an iOS app via iTunesConnect before app goes live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989885/submitting-third-version-of-an-ios-app-via-itunesconnect-before-app-goes-live?rq=1)

Basically the idea is you could set a future release date, and click the release button - the binary would not go out until that date, and theoretically then there would be some way in iTunes Connect to find a link to use to install the approved binary from Apple.

That is all hypothetical, the next time I have an application ready for release I will attempt that and adjust this answer (unless someone else provides a clear answer before me).

Comment: did you find a better answer?

Comment: Sorry, never did find an answer for this and have not had a chance to try again.