# Pending developer release and availability date

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I made the mistake of thinking that if I selected to manually release the app, that it would be released on the availability date I selected. My app is now in the 'Pending developer release' state and I was wondering if there was any way to still ensure that the app is released on the correct day without having to manually release it myself. If I click 'release this version', will the app be available immediately or will it be released on the availability date I selected?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be released on the availability date.  Though there is some confusion that seems to be the consensus.  Here are some other discussions on it:

[Submitting third version of an iOS app via iTunesConnect before app goes live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989885/submitting-third-version-of-an-ios-app-via-itunesconnect-before-app-goes-live)

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/120651-my-app-is-pending-developer-release-now-if-i-press-release-this-version.html